# Understanding Angular module scope (for ngx-bootstrap)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5, ngx-bootstrap, ng-modules

I'm kinda new to Angular and am having issues integrating ngx-bootstrap in my project when using ng modules...

To be more brief - **Everything works properly when I add html directly in app.component.html but won't work when I add the same code in app-*component* and declare it inside app.component.html**

---

Steps taken :

1. Used Angular CLI 1.7.4 to generate a new project (with Angular 5.2.9)
2. Used `npm install --save bootstrap ngx-bootstrap` and imported bootstrap.min.css in my style.css
3. Created a new module called 'app-bootstrap.module.ts' in src/app,and included the following in it :

```js
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
    
@NgModule({
    imports: [BsDropdownModule.forRoot()],
    exports: [BsDropdownModule]
})
export class AppBootstrapModule { }
```

> At this point, if I include the html code e.g. say for the dropdown button 
>   in `app.component.html` (after importing above module too), it works as expected. 
>   However, this is not what I want, so I went along with following steps.

4. Created a new component in 'dropdown' under src/app and included the following in it `dropdown.component.html` :

```html
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
    <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
      Button dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li role="menuitem">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li role="menuitem">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li role="menuitem">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li role="menuitem">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

5. Created a module called `custom-components.module.ts` in src/app and declared dropdown component inside it :

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DropdownComponent } from './dropdown/dropdown.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [DropdownComponent],
  exports: [DropdownComponent]
})
export class CustomComponentsModule { }
```

6. Imported `customComponentsModule` in `app.module.ts` as follows :

```js
//... Bootstrap and Components Modules
import { AppBootstrapModule } from './app-bootstrap.module';
import { CustomComponentsModule } from './custom-components.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CustomComponentsModule, //Custom Components
    AppBootstrapModule //Bootstrap Module
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

7. Added `<app-dropdown></app-dropdown>` inside `app.components.html`
8. **When I run `ng serve` here, the button shows up all styled up but when I click on it, nothing happens.** As mentioned before, dropdown works when I put the same code in `app.component.html` - this lead me to believe there is some scope issue I am not getting. Frustratingly enough, no errors show up.

Note :

1. I've used a 'dropdown' component just for sake of brevity.
2. If I have missed adding something important, kindly ask for same in comments and I'll provide it.

Apologies for the big post; any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: check this issue ..https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1402 .. you need to import `import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';` at the sub module also in `AppBootstrapModule`  and as usual in `AppModule` with `BsDropdownModule.forRoot()` , But it's better to have them at `AppModule` only.

Comment: Are you using it at the root module only ??

Comment: @Niladri Thanks for the reply, although I'm afraid the issue still remains. 

Here's what I tried :

1. Added ngx dropdown import to `app.module.ts` with forRoot()
2. Removed forRoot() method in `app-bootstrap.module.ts` but otherwise unchanged.

Also, since my code base is quite large, I do NOT want all the code in main module (hence the reason for me making multiple modules and the very question itself).

Comment: No need to import `import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';` in AppBootstrapModule

Comment: Well, I removed the entire import for AppBootstrapModule from AppModule. Still the same.

Comment: In case someone ends up here with the same problem as me, make sure you're importing into the right custom module! I was importing into another custom module that doesn't use ngx-bootstrap. Whoops.